# Clean/Pretty URLs with htaccess (special case)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've got this URL going on:

http://domain.com/edit.php?id=123

I've been searching and so far, everything I find is teaching me to modify htaccess so that it becomes:

http://domain.com/123/

My problem is, I also have `http://domain.com/delete.php?id=123`

So wouldn't it conflict since they would both be rewritten by htaccess to the same (`http://domain.com/123/`) ?

How can I make it so that

`http://domain.com/edit.php?id=123` --> `http://domain.com/edit/123`
`http://domain.com/delete.php?id=123` --> `http://domain.com/delete/123`
`http://domain.com/page.php` --> `http://domain.com/page`

Answer (score 1):

> So wouldn't it conflict since they would both be rewritten by htaccess to the same (http://domain.com/123/) ?

Yes, there is *no* way to tell if "123" should be routed to "edit" or "delete". You have to add the prefix like you've suggested. Via these rules in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^delete/([0-9]+)/? /delete.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^edit/([0-9]+)/? /edit.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Additionally, you can add these to externally redirect browsers to the nicer looking URL

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^.]+)\.php\?id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^.]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Whoops. Ignore the previous comment, deleted it. Just one question! Does this mean that all my links now need to be `<a href="http://domain.com/page/">` and not `<a href="http://domain.com/page.php">` ?